# Extract subtitles from DVD

Tags: gstreamer

So I have a DVD, part of a boxset, and I would like to extract the subtiles

Information about the disk:

```
$ gst-discoverer-1.0 /the/mounted/disk/VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB 
Analyzing file:///the/mounted/disk/VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB
Done discovering file:///the/mounted/disk/VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB

Topology:
  container: MPEG-2 System Stream
    audio: DVD AC-3 (ATSC A/52)
      audio: AC-3 (ATSC A/52)
    video: MPEG-2 Video (Main Profile)

Properties:
  Duration: 0:06:59.480000000
  Seekable: yes
  Live: no
  Tags: 
      audio codec: DVD AC-3 (ATSC A/52)
      bitrate: 384000
      video codec: MPEG-2 Video

$ gst-discoverer-1.0 /the/mounted/disk/VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_0.VOB
Analyzing file:///the/mounted/disk/VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_0.VOB
Done discovering file:///the/mounted/disk/VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_0.VOB

Topology:
  container: MPEG-2 System Stream
    subtitles: DVD subpicture
    subtitles: DVD subpicture
    video: MPEG-2 Video (Main Profile)

Properties:
  Duration: 0:00:00.049444444
  Seekable: yes
  Live: no
  Tags: 
      video codec: DVD subpicture
```

Ideally I'd end up with something like a vtt file at the end. I *do not* want the audio or video

I've played around with gst-launch and have watched the disk with `playbin` as well as doing various `filesrc` experiments, but looking at docs and old mailing list posts hasn't got me very far

I see `webvttenc` exists, but I'm really not sure how I get to the point where I can use it (how do I get from `subpicture/x-dvd` to `text/x-raw`?)

Really I've got no idea what I'm doing

Comment: Not that easy. DVD subtitles are images. So you would need to decode them and pass them to some OCR application.

Comment: I got that impression, of course if I could get to the point I've got a bmp of them all I could use something else to OCR them